# Ant design charts Space between points proportional to x-axis values

Tags: javascript, charts, antd, g2plot

How can I realise space between points **proportional** to x-axis values with `@ant-design/charts`. 
CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-williams-v5jx9?file=/src/Chart.jsx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the data type 'time'. Please, consider this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-rosalind-ujdl8?file=/src/Chart.jsx).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.